# Conditionally load css file in a polymer element

Tags: css, polymer

I have a bunch of css files that contains different animations and I would like to dynamically load a css file in a polymer element depending on the animation attribute:

would it be possible to bind the {{animation}} value like this:

```
<polymer-element name="yo-dialog" attributes="animation">
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="yo-dialog.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dialog.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dialog-{{animation}}.css">

        <div id="somedialog" class="dialog">
            <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
            <div class="dialog__content">            
                <content> </content>
                <div>
                    <button class="action" data-dialog-close>{{animation}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
```

Element usage:

```
<yo-dialog id="the_dialog" animation="ken">
    <h1>hello world</h1>
</yo-dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

When I had the same problem the quickest way I had found to solve it was programmatically add the link element when I knew that the attribute was set, i.e. on domReady event:

In your code, instead of the link tag, I would use tthe Polymer declaration:

```
<polymer-element name="yo-dialog" attributes="animation">
    <template>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="yo-dialog.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="dialog.css">

        <div id="somedialog" class="dialog">
            <div class="dialog__overlay"></div>
            <div class="dialog__content">            
                <content> </content>
                <div>
                    <button class="action" data-dialog-close>{{animation}}</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer("yo-dialog", {
        domReady: function() {
          var fileref=document.createElement("link")
          fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
          fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
          fileref.setAttribute("href", "dialog-"+this.animation+".css")
          console.log(fileref)
          this.appendChild(fileref)
          console.log("domReady!")

        }
      });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I've put a working sample in Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/IrN2FpDDN4PX1MVQqC1C?p=preview

Comment: working solution. except I had to use the `ready` property instead of `domReady`

Comment: The answer was done for an old (0.5 I think) Polymer version, where the livecycle method called when ready was `domReady`. In Polymer 1.0+ the method is indeed `ready`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You need to use the _ prefix for the href attribute so that it will resolve any template bindings.

Try:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" _href="dialog-{{animation}}.css">
```

Comment: Then I need to insert this `<link>` in the `<body>`, and even in the Polymer template, don't I?